# Yii2 enablePrettyUrl fail and frontend post request fail

Tags: yii2

i was trying to make 
this url 
http://localhost/advanced/frontend/web/index.php?r=test
into 
htttp://localhost/advanced/frontend/web/tests in yii2

also to receive post request

this in my codding in common/config/main.php

```
 <?php
 return [
  'vendorPath' => dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/vendor',
  'components' => [
  'cache' => [
      'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
  ],

  'urlManager' => [

   ],
   'urlManagerFrontEnd' => [
          'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
          'rules' => [
              [
                  'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
                  'controller' => ['test'],
                  'only' => ['index', 'create'],
              ],
          ],
          'showScriptName' => false,
    ],

 ],
];
```

this in my frontend testController

namespace frontend\controllers;

```
use Yii;
use yii\rest\ActiveController;
use common\models\Test;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
class TestController extends ActiveController {
    public $modelClass = 'common\models\Test';

    public function actions(){
        $actions = parent::actions();
        unset($actions['create']);
        return $actions;
    }

   public function actionCreate(){
       $model = new Test();
       $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post(),'');
       $model->save();
       return $model;
    }




}
```

i have a problem in the post request when i tried 
[Postman result jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjEDS.jpg)

so i have 2 problem the first is the prettyUrl  and the post request

if u have a solution please make it easy because i just learn php yii2 html css etc for 1 month

Comment: Just to be sure: do you have the corrsponding `.htaccess`-file in place? This asserts that urls to existing files and folders are not affected by the url-manager of yii2 and keep being accessed directly.